# Repair platform.xml

Tags: sd-card, 6.0-marshmallow

After upgrading to an experimental 6.0 build I've had some niggling issues. One of which was a bad WLAN config file, fixed with a delete. Second was SD Card being read only to some apps.

As a test I moved the platform.xml out to the SD and rebooted, to see if Android would generate its own (poor assumption), causing many apps to crash out, along with google play services.

I then moved it back, changed the perms to the normal for that directory, rebooted, but same issue. Cant find a way to restore the working state. Any suggestions how to fix it without a system wipe?

Comment: And it seems TWRP cant mount partitions now either, not good.